# Missing NFS service link?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

```
# ps ax | grep nfs
 1108 ?        S<     0:00 [nfsd4]
 1109 ?        S<     0:00 [nfsd4_callbacks]
 1110 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
 1111 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
 1112 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
 1113 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
 1114 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
 1115 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
 1116 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
 1117 ?        S      0:00 [nfsd]
 4437 ?        S<     0:00 [nfsiod]
16799 ?        S      0:00 [nfsv4.0-svc]
18091 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep nfs
```

But

```
# service nfs status
nfs: unrecognized service
```

That'll be on `Ubuntu 11.04` am I missing a sym link or something? How can I fix this quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
service nfs-kernel-server status
```

instead -- this is the name of the init script on Ubuntu systems.

It's worth noting that [11.04 reached end of life on 28th October 2012](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2012-October/000165.html), so it's worth considering an upgrade.

Comment: Yes thats the one, cheers. If only the OS was end of life on this pile  of scrap metal.. :)